# Xaml Error when creating our own content page

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I create a content page of my own called BaseContentpage. When I called it from my XAML page. It always gives a compile-time error. it is not issued when I run the app it runs smoothly. I cannot understand the problem.

My base content page

```
  public abstract class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public readonly BaseViewModel BaseViewModel;

    protected bool _isNavigated = false;

    public BaseContentPage(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
    {
        BaseViewModel = baseViewModel;
    }

    public abstract void Navigate(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e);
    protected abstract override void OnAppearing();
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        _isNavigated = true;
    }
}
```

My XAML Page

```
 <views:BaseContentPage
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DipsDemoXaml.Views.PatientListViewPage"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DipsDemoXaml.Views;assembly=DipsDemoXaml.Views"
         Title="{Binding PatientWard.Name}">
```

it gives a compile time error

Error   XLS0414 The type 'views: BaseContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  DipsDemoXaml    PatientListViewPage.xaml

How to fix this compile time error

Comment: Can you provide your sample?So that I can test it on my side.

Comment: Your BaseContentPage is abstract. How can you create a page of this type?

Comment: as you said I remove the abstract  it does not help to get rid of the error  it is compile time error  not run time one

Comment: when I add a default constructor to base content page the error disappear and working correctly. what is the concept of how my error disappear and I think it may cause a constructor overloading? Is that way I am suggesting is correct or wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you might want to add the default constructor:

```
 public BaseContentPage () :base()
 {

 }
```

Since Xaml by default access's this constructor, also call the `base()` constructor as that would initialize the base class constructor. (Not mandatory but, a good practice in my understanding mostly when you have constructor parameter that you want your base class constructor to initialize the base class with.)

Now since XAML is unable to find this it assumes that you might have not compiled your project properly or not having the proper assembly reference.

Hence the error

> The type 'views: BaseContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. DipsDemoXaml PatientListViewPage.xaml

Secondly, Abstract methods, are declared without any implementation. They are declared with the purpose of having the child class provide an implementation. They must be declared within an abstract class. A class declared abstract may or may not include abstract methods. They are created with the purpose of being a superclass. So I personally do not think that your scenario needs an abstract class(I could be wrong).

Good luck, In case of queries feel free to revert.